# How to align v-text-field label using reverse tag in Vuetify.js?

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have used vuetify.js as UI framework in Nuxt.js my latest project.
In v-text-field component, I tried to user reverse tag to move text align right. But I didn't move label from align left to align right.
I used reverse, label was automatically move to align right.

So, I tried to fix like below.
in template↓

```html
<v-text-field
  class="label-left"
  reverse
  label="TOTAL"
  persistent-placeholder
  dense
  outlined
  v-model="totalCost"
></v-text-field>
```

and add style↓

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>
div ::v-deep .v-label.v-label--active.theme--light {
  left: 0 !important;
  transform-origin: top left !important;
  position: absolute !important;
}
</style>
```

but result was like below↓
[image]

I want to fix the border space to label position.
Does anyone advise me,please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **need to use `reverse`** (for some other reason), repositioning the label is possible with the following styles:

1. Override the `left` and `right` position of the `.v-label` to `0` and `auto`, respectively.
2. The gap seen on the border is implemented with a `<legend>` element. Override its `width` (which is dynamically calculated at runtime) with `auto` (may need specific width adjustment based on the label's actual width); and set its `margin-left` to `10px`.

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>
1️⃣
div ::v-deep .v-label.v-label--active.theme--light {
  left: 0 !important;
  right: auto !important;
}

2️⃣
div ::v-deep .v-input__slot fieldset legend {
  margin-left: 10px !important;
  width: auto;
}
</style>
```

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/gOGggxd)

On the other hand, if you **don't need `reverse`**, you could avoid the custom positioning of the label, and change the `input`'s direction to `rtl`:

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>
div ::v-deep .v-input__slot input {
  direction: rtl;
}
</style>
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/KKXaaRw)